# Modifying emacs toolbar font size

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

My fontsize for emacs tool bar (file/edit/options/...) and edited buffer became (inexplicably) larger than before...

I corrected the font size of the buffer adding `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 70)` in my init.el, but I don't know how to reduce the toolbar font size. I am under kubuntu 14.04. I tried modifying the `system settings -> application appearence -> fonts` but it didn't work.

Any idea?

**EDIT**: This font size problem occurred after that I undocked my laptop and redocked it, but I didn't change anything on purpose. Some other "size" problems occured, like in thunderbird where everything (font, icons, ...) became larger than before...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I know this problem: your emacs is compiled with gtk and its UI font is controlled by the gtk settings, not the kde settings, nor emacs settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"became (inexplicably) larger than before..." is unclear. When? Did you change something? Emacs version? Platform changes? Not enough information to go on.

The Emacs tool bar depends on your platform and the toolkit used (if any). But if both buffer text size and tool-bar icon size changed then I would suspect a change in resolution. Does the size change affect everything or just Emacs?

---

After your update, indicating that size was changed in other places (everyplace?), I suspect a display resolution change.  In any case, given that the problem is not limited to Emacs, so I've removed the `emacs` tag.

Comment: I edited the question with respect with your answer. Thanks